# Blazor WebAssembly new project does not allow .NET 5 selection

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

When I create a new Blazor server project in Visual Studio, it shows .NET 5 in the framework selection dropdown but when I create a new Blazor WebAssembly project it does not. How do I get it to allow me to select .NET 5 for a Wasm project. If I try and change the project file it gives an error. I have .NET 5 installed obviously as it allows it for server projects. I have the latest version of Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: You select .NET5 before you select what type of Blazor project, so the way you've worded your question makes it sound like you are doing something different. The process should be : Create a new project...Choose "Blazor App"...Give it a name and location...Choose .NET 5...Choose Server or WebAssembly

Comment: Thanks, that worked.